# Inequality: $\left|x^3-y^3\right|<|x|^3+|y|^3$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, absolute-value

Could anyone show me why

$$\left|x^3-y^3\right|<|x|^3+|y|^3$$
for all real numbers (x,y) except 0?

I'm thinking of whether of how to remove the modulus sign on the left hand side of 
the equation maybe using a distance formula. Should I raise the left hand side to the power of 
2 to remove the modulus?

Comment: We need conditions on $x$ and $y$. Are they both *positive*? Or else do you want to replace $\lt$ by $\le$?

Comment: It's not true, but $|x^3-y^3|\leq |x|^3+|y|^3$ is. For example, when $x=1,y=-1$, you get equality.

Comment: @Thomas: You are totally right, that's why I erased my post. Actually it doesn't work for all $$(x,y)\in\{(a,b)\mid a=-b\}$$ Tks.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$|x^3 - y^3| = |x^3 + (-y^3)| \leq |x^3| + |(-y^3)| = |x^3| + |y^3|$$

The $\leq$ part comes from the triangle inequality ($|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$)